# Laravel 5.4: Submit a HTML form and receive a JSON response

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, controller

Question: how can I communicate JSON back from a controller to my html page, and embed the response in my page, instead of destroying the page?

The long story is like this:

Embedded in a quite large html page (created by a view when I open my base URL, say, http://.../home) I have a html form. It has some data fields, and the usual "Submit" button.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('form.user') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    ... lots of input fields ...

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The receiving route ...

```
Route::post('form/user','ItemController@save')->name('form.user');
```

And the controller ...

```
public function save(Request $request) {

...
return response()->json(['status' => 'Saved successfully']);
```

}

The whole thing works like intended, if I fill the form and hit the "Submit" button, the controller receives all input fields via the $request properties.

The problem arises after the return from the controller, the html is cleared from the browser, and the JSON is displayed.

What I need is receive the JSON and display it in a div of my original html, not replace it.

Question: what do I need to do, how can I hook into the communication to intercept and handle the JSON response, so I can display the response text in my original web page (using JQuery), and not destroy the html?

Thx, Armin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Capture the FORM submit event, and prevent the default.
2. Construct an AJAX request
3. Dictate the response type.
4. Convert the form data to a serialized object to be sent to the server
5. Capture the returned response and apply it to a DIV.

That would look something like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //1

    var $this = $(this); //alias form reference

    $.ajax({ //2
        url: $this.prop('action'),
        method: $this.prop('method'),
        dataType: 'json',  //3
        data: $this.serialize() //4
    }).done( function (response) {
        if (response.hasOwnProperty('status')) {
            $('#target-div').html(response.status); //5
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks promising, thank you very much, I'll give it a try today, and let you know what happens.

Comment: Sorry, same problem.
.success is obviously never called, Instead the returned JSON is displayed in the browser. Do I need to add something to the response on the server side so the browser doesn't try to display it?

Comment: @Nimral Do you, you need to `e.preventDefault()` to make sure that the default action of the form submitting to the server doesn't occur.

Comment: The preventDefault is in place,the code I use is almost a 100% copy of the sample you gave me.

Comment: Code is working! I had a few more lines in mine. Trying to track the problem I commented out several lines, and suddenly the code started working. I haven't found out yet which weird side effect broke it, but anyway, the reson is somewhere in my part, not in yours. Sometimes this code injection stuff gets a bit complex. Thanks!

Comment: @Nimral If you edit the post and share your code, I'm happy to try and help.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind offer to help, but I figured it out myself. .success() is now .done(), .error is now .fail(). Changed the keywords, and my simplified code worked right away. The reasons why the json appeared on screen were related to .success not having run, I hope that my full code, once I have reversed the simplifications, runs as well, but I am optimistic (as always) that things go smooth from now on.

Comment: @Nimral That's a great point! I haven't used jQuery in years, so I'd forgotten about the deprecations and changes in 3.x +. Glad you got it to work!